# "The identity of the web site or the integrity of this connection cannot be verified"

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio

I'm using Windows 10 and I often get a notification of some kind telling me that "The identity of the web site or the integrity of this connection cannot be verified".

It happens (I believe) when running Visual Studio 2015, although the windows don't close with it. Also I cannot find the process causing it via task bar or task manager.

Also, the longer VS is open, the more windows appear. I left it open over night and when I came back to my PC there were hundreds, if not thousands of windows (the shadow overlaps and it's pitch black, that's how I know there are many windows open).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Next time click "View Certificate" and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more likely the cookie you downloaded for that site has expired. Just clear cookies and then see if the popup come out again or not. Try it! It's help :)

Comment: How does one clear cookies in visual studio?